# Background size cover plus background attachment fixed not working in pages with scrolling in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've always been using the following piece of code to make a background fixed as well as covering 100% of the page despite its size:

```
background-image: url('./background.jpg'); 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: center top;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

However, since IE11, this is not working as it should:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZK4M.png]

This is how it was showing up until IE11:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bkmH.jpg]

Did anything change with IE11? Is there any way to make it work as before IE11?

Comment: What happens if you change it to `background-size: contain;` instead?

Comment: This part of code is ok and works from IE 9 up to IE 11. It has to be something else. Have you got any X-UA-Compatible meta tag?

Comment: I didn't know about either until I read the question. It seems that `cover` stretches the image so that it fills out the full background, even if there is overflow with the proportions, while `contain` stretches the background so that it fits inside the background, but will resize with the window to ensure that the full image is visible, based on it's proportions. In any case, I would makes sure the rule is being applied to the `body` element and not a smaller container.

Comment: @Andy - Dude, I don't use IE and now that I'm on a mac I have a great excuse other than "who cares" as to why. And yes, if it works in IE10 but doesn't in IE11, something changed. But you are going to have more success fixing your css than finding out what changed, filing a bug with MS, and having them fix it before IE13, so you are better off not worrying about IE11 if you know for a fact it's working in every other browser including earlier IE versions.

Comment: @Andy - to put that more politely - if something breaks in one browser and no others, it's the browser that's broken, not your code, and if everyone stops trying to accommodate for that one browser, users will notice that *lots* of unrelated pages look broken in that one browser, and switch to a better browser, forcing that browser to fix the issue to prevent further user loss, rather than expecting developers to adapt for every quirk in every version they release.

Comment: @Anthony You'd hope. :) A lot of (older) people don't seem to understand the internet. They fall for everything, including Microsoft's "IE makes the web the prettiest". The biggest thing that gets me is when IE puts "This webpage is not responding" like trying to blame the developer and not IE, when it's really the other way around. I don't even test my pages in IE. And when someone else (a user) *does* "test" it, no one is happy. Oh well...

(If the reader is an older person, please don't take offense. There are some old people who are really with tech.)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your comments!
I found a way that actually Works in IE11. Placing the background as an image in an individual div with these properties:

`code height: auto;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
 z-index:-1;`

Check it here:
http://nekutranslations.es/sf2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your comments! I found a way that actually Works in IE11. Placing the background as an image in an individual div with these properties: code height: auto; left: 0; min-height: 100%; min-width: 1024px; position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; z-index:-1; Check it here: nekutranslations.es/sf2